# How to use Swift and Combine to publish results of calls to a function with coded termination logic?

Tags: swift, combine

I’m curious, how do we use Combine to publish the results of a function until a certain answer is received?

For the purposes of this example, let’s say I’m using this function:

```swift
func guessANumber() -> Int { Int.random(in: 0...9) }
```

I want to use Combine to publish a sequence of results from this function that will terminate when it receives zero as the output. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a lazy `Sequence` that does that, using [`sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence(first:next:)).

```
let seq = sequence(first: guessANumber()) { _ in
    let number = guessANumber()
    return number == 0 ? nil : number
}
```

If you really want, you can turn this into a `Publisher` using the `publisher` property:

```
let publisher = seq.publisher
```

Alternatively, make an infinite sequence, and use the `prefix(while:)` operator:

```
sequence(first: guessANumber()) { _ in guessANumber() }
    // .publisher // prefix(while:) is also a Combine operator
    .prefix(while: { $0 != 0 })
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! A gold-mine of information. Thank you, kind person!